# Weylus for windows setup

Tags: drawing, tablet, gimp

I was trying to use my galaxy tab s4 as graphic tablet without paying, and I used weylus to use it. I found the version that supports tilt and pressure on windows from https://github.com/kotaewing/Weylus/releases/tag/V1.1 here and I tested on https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/pen-tracker/ here. So weylus can get pressure and tilt information, so I want to use it on other programs like krita or GIMP. how should I set it up to use tilt and pressure? or even what programs should I use?